# Django - manager on ManyToMany relationship

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have 3 models

```py
class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Company(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  members = models.ManyToManyField (Person, through = 'Membership', related_name = 'companies')

class Membership(models.Model):
  person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  is_admin = models.BooleanField()
```

I can then call `person.companies.all()` to get the list of companies associated with person.

How do I create a manager to have the list of companies associated with person, but whose person is admin (is_admin = True)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a manager like the following:

`managers.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class AdminCompaniesManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().companies.filter(membership__is_admin=True)
```

and then in your `Person` model (please remind the `objects` manager):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    objects = models.Manager()
    administered_companies = AdminCompaniesManager()
```

Now you can easily call the following (e.g. in your views):

```
my_person.administered_companies.all()
```

PS: a very efficient option (e.g. if you are in a view and you need the list of company ids by a given person) is to query the membership model directly, so you can optimize the query for data retrieval from DB avoiding the joins:

```
Membership.objects.filter(is_admin=True, person=person).values_list('company_id')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with:

```
person.companies.filter(membership__is_admin=True)
```

This will filter the junction table `Membership`, such that it will only retrieve `Company`s for which the `Membership` has `is_admin` set to `True`.

Another option is to retrieve this with:

```
Company.objects.filter(membership__is_admin=True, members=person)
```

You can attach this to the `Person` model with:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    @property
    def admin_companies(self):
        return self.companies.filter(membership__is_admin=True)
```